# How to colorize the Powershell prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell-5.0

I always make my prompt to be this color in my linux
[image]
Then I can find my input in the black command window. But can we make the same color in my *Powershell*?

Comment: What is the console font?

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Look [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmT90.png), maybe it is *Sim song* in English.

Comment: This is SimSun maybe?

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Yes, sorry I make a mistake.

Comment: not your fault, transliteration is hard

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[image: screenshot of coloured prompt]

## PowerShell prompts

What you want to do is customise the [prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts).

The default prompt in PowerShell 3.0 and newer is:

```
function prompt  
{  
    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "  
}
```

---

## Colour escape sequences

Now, Windows 10 [supports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting) the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in its conhost, and [24-bit colour](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/) is supported since 1703.

To use one of the ANSI escape codes, we need a literal [ESC character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character). This is octal 033, or decimal 27. In Bash, you would use `"\033"` or `"\e"`; There's no direct equivalent sequence in PowerShell but you can instead embed an expression: `"$([char]27)"`

In PowerShell Core you can use the `` "`e" `` escape sequence instead. [Thanks to the comment by asherber.](https://superuser.com/questions/1259900/how-to-colorize-the-powershell-prompt/1259916?noredirect=1#comment2285569_1259916)

---

### Use in PowerShell

This means you can, for example, use the following escape sequence to set the background colour to cyan with the code `46`:

```
"$([char]27)[46m"
```

Which can be used like so:

```
echo "$([char]27)[46mColoured text"
```

To make things more readable, let's define a variable:

```
$ESC = [char]27
```

So we can use:

```
"$ESC[46m"
```

Where `$ESC` is the literal ESC character, `[` defines the start of the param list, and `m` the end.

Using it in a command:

```
echo "$ESC[46mColoured text"
```

And to restore the original colour settings, we use the code `0` instead:

```
echo "$ESC[46mColoured text$ESC[0mUncoloured text"
```

### More advanced colours

If you aren't happy with the basic 16-colour palette, you can use full 24-bit colours with the form:

```
"$ESC[48;2;<r>;<g>;<b>m"
```

Where `<r>` is the decimal value for red from 0-255, `<g>` for green and `<b>` for blue, e.g. `"$ESC[48;2;255;0;123m"`

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting) for more information.

In fact, this is all directly equivalent to what you would do in bash, except you need to use `$ESC` (after you've defined it) instead of `\e` or `\033`.

---

## Setting a coloured prompt

Putting these together, we can use the ANSI colour escape codes in a modified prompt to change the background colour:

```
function prompt  
{  
    $ESC = [char]27
    "$ESC[46mPS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $ESC[0m"  
}
```

---

### Persistence

If you want this to persist across sessions, add it to your profile (like `.bashrc`). You can view the path to your profile in `$profile`.

Comment: Hi~,it is a great answer..But further more, could we make the text be [bold style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJWEB.png)?Then we can find it more easy..

Comment: @yode You can add the code `1` to enable the bold/bright option, e.g. `$ESC[46;1m`. However, it looks like conhost currently does not support an actual bold typeface — it just uses a bright foreground colour. You can add `4` for an underline if you prefer.

Comment: Crazy man. Could you tell me how do you find this information?

Comment: @yode It's more or less all documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting), which I linked in the answer ;)

Comment: As your lilnk, it seem the 91 is what I after. But is seem it doesn't work..

Comment: Instead of defining `$ESC`, why not define things like `$RED`, `$BLUE` and `$OFF`. I think that would really enhance readability. `"This ${BLUE}phrase is blue${OFF} and ${RED}this one is red${OFF}."`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson There's enough different cases that I think it gets unwieldy - how do you distinguish between blue background and foreground? And you can change multiple formatting settings in a single command, e.g. colour + underline. It makes more sense if you need it across many commands, e.g. `$COLOUR_ERROR`. But that's not really useful for a prompt line. `$ESC` was done so it can be more or less a drop-in replacement for the same command in bash (`\e`).

Comment: @yode In what way does it not work? What command did you use exactly? That won't give you bold but it should give you a bright red foreground colour.

Comment: It is seem get a [same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2jmZ.png)

Comment: @yode Ah. If you compare to 37 non-bright white, it looks like PowerShell windows already use 97 bright white by default. (btw, there's going to be a [new colour palette](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/02/updating-the-windows-console-colors/) for clean installs of the next Win10 version. There's some screenshots there of the [current palette](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/08/ConsoleChangesSideBySideNoBar1.png); note that `1;37m` is the same as `97m`, both meaning "bright white")

Comment: @yode Basically, conhost does not yet support bold. Bright is a substitute for bold, and you're already using the bright colour by default. If you really want bold, you can use an alternative terminal, such as [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/FaqBoldItalic.html) — but it looks like their support for ANSI bold isn't complete either. IMO, it isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: I can't get the Markdown to work correctly, but in PowerShell Core you can use backtick+e for `[char]27`. I'm not sure if this was added in earlier versions.

Comment: @asherber Thanks. I've added a mention but I'll keep the rest of the answer valid for older PowerShell versions. I've just confirmed that the version bundled with Win10 does not support that escape sequence.