# Adding ForeGround Color to Powershell profile?

Tags: powershell, colors

I use the following to wrap my location in:

```
function prompt 
{ 
    if ($isAdmin) 
    {
        "[" + (Get-Location) + "] # "
    }
    else 
    {
        "[" + (Get-Location) + "] $ "
    }
}
```

This renders a location listing like so:

[image: Location]

How can I color the location in using ForeGround color? I tried appending it but it did not work. I am not really sure what to do here, as I don't know how to apply a color to something that isn't `WriteHost` or `WriteColor` module.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to colorize the Powershell prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/1259900/how-to-colorize-the-powershell-prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible by using `Write-Host`.

For example, this simple Prompt method sets the color of the prompt to yellow:

```
function Prompt
{
    $promptString = "PS " + $(Get-Location) + ">"
    Write-Host $promptString -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    return " "
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works great! Appreciate it :D