# Is there a way to give the current path different color in Windows Terminal?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I use Windows Terminal,
I'm looking for a way to customize the current path color so it stands out in the terminal window, and I can identify it quickly, most coloring schemes only customize the font color regardless of its role (path or command).

[image]

Comment: That's going to be a feature of the shell, rather than the terminal.  Assuming that's PowerShell, as in your screenshot.  Searching for *PowerShell color prompt* led me to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1259916/1210833) that you should read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to colorize the Powershell prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/1259900/how-to-colorize-the-powershell-prompt).  You will need to modify the example slightly to wrap the path function in the colors rather than the whole prompt, but all the info you need should be there.

Comment: Yes, it does, except that I can't find the shell file (as returned from `$profile`): `C:\Users\mshawaf\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` doesn't exist on my machine.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point.  You do have to create the profile and give it permissions to execute.  If it doesn't exist, then use `New-Item –Path $Profile –Type File -Force` to create the file.  Then you'll need `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` to allow it to run without signing.

Comment: Great, thanks :)